# How to get stockBalance of every end of the month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Four columns like

```
Date            Customer        InvoiceNo            StockBalance
11/29/2017       A               IN000414             5000
11/30/2017       B               IN000415             4000 
12/27/2017       A               IN000416             3500
12/30/2017       B               IN000417             2000
```

I want to get Stockbalance of every end of month, I need the output as

```
11/30/2017       B               IN000415             4000 
12/30/2017       B               IN000417             2000
```

how could i get this could anybody guide to me?

Comment: Please show what you've tried already.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc...) that you are using.

Comment: based on what criteria ??

Comment: Hi Sqlserver is using  and the criiteria is  end of every month in date column

Comment: I tried  but onlly get the  end of date   
  SELECT distinct DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,date)+1,0)) as Date FROM  ChandraLog.dbo.Log 
but how to get stock balance of  every month end of date

Comment: Create Table tst1 (Dat Datetime, Customer varchar(55),InvoiceNo float,StockBalance float);
INSERT INTO  tst1 (Dat, Customer,InvoiceNo,StockBalance) VALUES           
    (11/29/2017 , 'A',415,5000)
   ,(11/30/2017 , 'B', 416,4300)
   ,(11/30/2017 , 'C', 417,4000)
   ,(12/27/2017 , 'A',418,3500)
   ,(12/30/2017, 'B',419,2000)

   select t.*
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by month(dat) order by dat desc) seq
      from   tst1 
     ) t
where seq = 1;  I need the result as every end date of month stock bal
 (11/30/2017 ,  'C', 417,4000)
 ,(12/30/2017 ,  'B',419,2000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` function :

```
select t.*
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by year(date), month(date) order by date desc) seq
      from table
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

**EDIT** : You want `apply` :

```
select t.*
from table t cross apply
     ( select top (1) t1.*
       from table t1
       where t1.Customer = t.Customer and
             EOMONTH(t1.Dat) = t.Dat
       order by t1.Dat desc
     ) t1;
```

Comment: Hi i execute your query  but not get the correct answer.

Comment: Create Table tst1 (Dat Datetime, Customer varchar(55),InvoiceNo float,StockBalance float);
INSERT INTO  tst1 (Dat, Customer,InvoiceNo,StockBalance) VALUES           
    (11/29/2017 ,  'A',415,5000)
   ,(11/30/2017 ,  'B', 416,4300)
   ,(11/30/2017 ,  'C', 417,4000)
   ,(12/27/2017 ,  'A',418,3500)
   ,(12/30/2017 ,  'B',419,2000)

   select t.*
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by month(dat) order by dat desc) seq
      from   tst1 
     ) t
where seq = 1;

Comment: I need the result as every end date of month stock balance
 (11/30/2017,'C', 417,4000)
 ,(12/30/2017,'B',419,2000)

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`, but be sure you include the year and month in the calculation:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year(date), month(date)
                                order by date desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```